# Is there any way to re-mount an ejected USB device on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, usb

I wanted to know if is possible to mount a USB device after it has been removed from the Finder, without having to re-insert it into the USB port.

On my Mac I connected a USB device, but sometimes after putting the Mac suspended, the USB is no longer detected, and then I take it out and insert it again.

Is there any command line to reactivate? I tried with `diskutil mountDisk` but it does not work, as if the USB device is removed physically from Mac.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40112/how-do-i-mount-ejected-external-usb-flash-storage & it's linked duplicate, for a whole slew of ideas

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know if is possible to mount a USB device after it has
>   been removed from the Finder, without having to re-insert it into the
>   USB port.

If you are talking about USB devices in general? The answer is yes and no depending on the type of device ejected: Yes if it is a mounted hard drive—or SSD drive—but no if it is a USB flash drive. Details below.

### Works for USB Hard Disk Drives

#### Ejecting a USB hard disk drive and attempting to remount it with `diskutil mountDisk`.

For example, here is example `diskutil list` output from my Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) machine with one USB external hard drive connected and one USB flash drive connected:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Hard Drive              499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS External Hard Drive     2.0 TB     disk2s2
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS USB Flash Drive         7.7 GB     disk3s2
```

Okay, so now I go ahead and eject the “External Hard Drive” and check `diskutil list` again and the output looks 100% the same as mounted:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Hard Drive              499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS External Hard Drive     2.0 TB     disk2s2
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS USB Flash Drive         7.7 GB     disk3s2
```

So now if I wanted to remount “External Hard Drive” I would just need to note the partition identifier for “External Hard Drive” (`disk2s2`) and run this command:

```
diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2s2
```

Wait for the process to complete and the volume will be mounted as expected.

### Doesn’t Work for USB Flash Drives

#### Ejecting a USB flash drive and attempting to remount it with `diskutil mountDisk`.

But if I go ahead and eject the “USB Flash Drive” and then run `diskutil list` again, “USB Flash Drive” is removed from the list:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Hard Drive              499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS External Hard Drive     2.0 TB     disk2s2
```

And even if I attempt to mount that USB flash drive knowing the mount point from the previous list like this:

```
diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk3s2
```

The system says:

```
Unable to find disk for /dev/disk3s2
```

What explains this discrepancy in behavior? Unsure. But what it boils down to is if the USB device is a hard disk drive or SSD and it shows up in the list returned by `diskutil list`, then you should have no problems remounting the USB device. But if it is a USB flash drive and doesn’t show up in that list? It can’t be remounted unless the USB flash drive is physically unplugged and replugged-in again.

### Works for USB Flash Drives

#### Unloading and reloading the USB mass storage kernel extension (`IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext`).

All of that said, [the comment on this answer by Jannis Linxweiler](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40112/how-do-i-mount-ejected-external-usb-flash-storage#comment61310_53590) explains how if you unload and reload the USB mass storage kernel extension (`IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext`) you can effectively get the USB flash drive to remount without physically unplugging it.

Tested this on my Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) machine and it works as expected.

First, eject the USB flash drive and then run this command to unload `IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext`:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext
```

Then run this command to reload the `IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext`:

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext
```

Did that and my USB flash drive came back up without physically touching it. Neat trick! And it does not impact connected USB hard disk drives from what I can tell.